# Как добавить «подсветку» цвета и автодополнение в компонентах Vue в VS Code?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

В проекте на Vue есть файл sass с переменными подключенный глобально через vue.config.js

WebStorm, например, умеет зная имя переменной показывать какой в ней цвет и даже делать автодополнение. Можно ли научить такому VS Code?

[image: Example]

Comment: Может быть поможет это как альтернативное [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297941/vue-single-file-component-imported-scss-intellisense)

Comment: Так и было раньше, но, к сожалению, проблему это не решало.